# What was the alphanumeric graphic script written on the obelisk on planet "Eden" in the Stargate Universe episode "Faith"..?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

[image: SGU obelisk on planet Eden]

Has anyone come across an image from a *Stargate Universe* Set Prop model or CGI image developer which shows a close-up of the Obelisk model?

I am interested in trying to apply thought toward understanding the meaning behind the Obelisk artifact in the given context of the show.  If the Obelisk script was letters (phonics based), then it represents a spoken expression of intelligible thought.  If the script was numerals (binary or a base number system) then it may represent not only a coordinate location but perhaps also elude to the possible physical form of its creator.. such as how our base 10 system reflects our 10 digit finger appendages.  And other base number systems touch upon specific intellectual concepts.  So on and so forth.

If anyone has the resource availability to provide this image script, please do.

Comment: Please keep in mind, if the story writers did place a script on the side of that obelisk, it's unlikely to be anything more than decorative. If it was meant to be decrypted like the alien language during the title sequence of *Futurama,* it would have been shown in detail in the episode (otherwise, why pay for its creation? The economics of entertainment are ruthless). If it said anything at all, I'd expect to discover it said something along the lines of "there was once a girl from Nantucket...."

Comment: series writer Joseph Mallozzi says of these aliens "We never got that far, but I envisioned them as lifeforms vastly different than humans." (https://josephmallozzi.com/2011/05/14/may-14-2011-author-marjorie-m-liu-answers-your-questions-stargate-sg-1-memories-i-field-your-stargate-universe-queries-and-more/). This suggests there is no definitive answer, in terms of anything the SGU writers actually committed to, even if there are some inadvertent traces e.g. "the kind of beings who think obelisks are a neat idea".

Comment: Is there any reason to believe it has anything on it? I can't see any in the screenshot.

Comment: At 24:05 in that episode one of the scientists is looking up from the base of the obelisk and there is a much closer shot. The only video I have access to at present is too low resolution to see any characters, and there is glare from sunlight. But someone else could look.